# How to install or upgrade in ansible all packages in a yum repository

Tags: repository, ansible, yum

I want install all packages from my repo, I can't repeat this command:

```
yum repo-pkgs reponame install
```

in Ansible playbook.

All what i found it: example how install one package or list of know packages:

```
- name: upgrade all packages
  yum: name=* state=latest
```

not work:  write all packages installed 
-but it not right

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As the [documentation](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/yum_module.html#examples) suggests, the following task will update all already installed packages, not install available ones:

```
- name: upgrade all packages
  yum: 
    name: '*'
    state: latest
```

To achieve what you want, you need first to register the list of packages returned by your first command:

```
- name: gather list of packages available
  shell: yum repo-pkgs reponame list
  register: packages

- name: install/upgrade all packages
  yum: 
    name: "{{packages.stdout_lines|join(',')}}"
    state: latest
```

Disclaimer: this was not tested, so it may need adjusting.

Comment: thank's for answer, and the towards a solution. In your example packages.stdout_lines|join(',')  needed more parsing, because all word from stdout are separated with commas  and substitutied  in var name

Comment: How can I restrict this to only install security update? (See question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39450744/how-to-install-security-updates-on-amazon-ec2-runnign-machine-using-ansible)

Comment: Just one small note... your first recommendation worked for me but since I'm very new to Ansible, I had to review the documentation to see why my syntax wasn't correct. In vscode, when I typed the first code section you have labeled "upgrade all packages", I got a syntax error. I had to add a new line after yum:. Additionally, I had to add single quotes around the * like so: name: '*'. This is all in the documentation. Just a small note to those new to the language like myself. Thank you for the information and useful link!